# How do I find the Nth element in a binary search tree?

Tags: c, recursion, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I have a binary search tree in C, the goal currently is to find the Nth element in the tree. I am attempting to do this recursively, however this is not paramount. I have access to the amount of nodes under any given node (inclusive).

I tried this block of code:

```
TreeNode* findNthElement(int N, TreeNode* tree) {
  static int count = 0;
  printf("nodeCount: %d\nN: %d\nCount: %d\n", tree->nodeCount, N, count);//debug
  //null case
  if (tree == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }
  //recursion
  if (count <= N) {
    findNthElement(N, tree->left);
    count++;
    if (count == N) {
      count = 0;
      return tree;
    }
    findNthElement(N, tree->right);
  }
}
```

This is supposed to be a recursive function to complete my task but `count`'s value is always 0 even though it is static. I have also tried initializing count outside of the function and resetting it to 0 upon success or failure but that has also not succeeded.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre]. Clarify the statement “`count`'s value is always 0”: How did you observe the value of `count` and when?

Comment: Do not use `static int` to keep information in a recursive function. If you need additional information in a call, you should pass it as an argument. But, in this case, you do not need additional information. To find the Nth element (starting from 1st, not 0th): Let L and R be the numbers of nodes in the left and right subtrees. If N is greater than the number of nodes in the current tree, there is no Nth node. Otherwise, if N ≤ L, the Nth node is the Nth node of the left subtree. Otherwise, if N is L+1, it is the current node. Otherwise, it is the (N-L-1)th node of the right subtree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code ignores the node that is returned from the recursive call, so if that recursive call had found the target node, the caller is not aware of it. Moreover, after the `findNthElement(N, tree->right)` call, nothing is returned.

Also, you shouldn't use a static count. The counting logic can be satisfied by *reducing* the value that will be passed as N-argument to the recursive call.

Here is an implementation:

```
TreeNode* findNthElement(int n, TreeNode* tree) {
    if (tree == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    int currentNum = tree->left == NULL ? 1 : tree->left->nodeCount + 1;
    return n == currentNum ? tree // Found it!
         : n <  currentNum ? findNthElement(n, tree->left) 
                           : findNthElement(n - currentNum, tree->right);
}
```

Comment: We could consider deleting `|| tree->nodeCount < n`. That case will fall through to the recursion to the right subtree, which will eventually return null at a leaf. That trades a test of `tree->nodeCount < n` in every call (common) for a wasted traversal when the test would be true (likely rare).

Comment: Agreed. Removed that condition. Thanks, Eric. I guess with the same reasoning we could remove the `n < 1` condition as well.

Comment: This worked after the edit! Thanks for the help trincot and Eric!

Answer (score -1):

this code is beyond my knowledge, but maybe `count++` needs to go **before** recursing? Because you are calling the recursion without increasing the count in your code.
Example:

```
if (count <= N) {
    count++;
    findNthElement(N, tree->left);
```

Answer (score -1):

You dont have to define count as static at all, you can directly increment parameter and call recursively until N == count.
Whenever you call the function, even recursively, then a new count variable will be created in the memory stack.

```
TreeNode* findNthElement(int N, TreeNode* tree, int count) {
    TreeNode * nthTree = NULL;
    if(tree == NULL) 
        return NULL;

    //Found the Nth element
    if (count == N){
       return tree;
    }
    
    //Not using ++count just for clarity
    //First it will check left subtree, if its Nth then return it else go right
    nthTree = findNthElement(N, tree->left, count+1); //Recursive call for left node

    //Recursive call for right node
    return (nthTree == NULL) ? findNthElement(N, tree->right, count+1) : nthTree; 
     
}
```

Comment: How can this work? Suppose we have a binary tree with a left subtree containing just A, a root containing B, and a right subtree containing C. If we use zero-based ordinarys, A is 0th, B is 1st, and C is 2nd. If the caller wants the 1st node and calls `findNthElement(1, tree, 0)`, the `count == N` fails, so the routine makes the recursive calls, neither of which can find B.

Comment: @EricPostpischil when N == Count fails the program calls function with left subtree (A here) and it also increases the count by one in arguments. So, now in this call N == count is true and it will return the Node A.

Comment: A is the wrong answer. The 1st node is B, not A

Comment: @EricPostpischil that depends on pre/in/post order too. i took it as inorder traversal tho

Comment: Additionally, `findNthElement(N, tree->left, count+1);` cannot return anything to the caller of the current function instance. The only `return` statements in the code in this answer are `return tree;` and `return NULL;`, so it can only return the passed `tree` or `NULL`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil yea that was a mistake i updated that to return values

Answer (score -2):

in order to find the nth smallest element in BST, you can apply logic as follows:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
public int smallElement(int k)
{
    Node<T> node = Root;
    int count = k;
    int sizeOfSubTree =0;
    
    while (node != null)
    {
        sizeOfSubTree = node.SizeOfLeftSubTree();
        if(sizeOfSubTree +1 == count)
        {
            return node.Value;
        }
        else if(sizeOfSubTree +1 < count)
        {
            node=node.Right;
            count -= sizeOfSubTree +1 ;
            
        }
        else
        {
            
            node = node.Right;
        }
        
    }
    return -1;
    
    
}
```

you can also check following resources to get help:

[in-order traversal to find nth node](https://www.codespeedy.com/find-the-n-th-node-of-the-inorder-traversal-of-a-binary-tree-in-cpp/)

[Find k’th smallest node in a Binary Search Tree (BST)](https://www.techiedelight.com/find-kth-smallest-node-binary-search-tree/)

hope this might help you.

Comment: I believe that is the wrong language my guy.  That looks like `C#`.  OP is asking about C.